# IntelliJ: customize naming of generated test methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

If I generate test for a class which has let's say `getId()` method the corresponding test method will be called `getId()` as well.

Is it possible to setup IntelliJ to add some static prefix for automatically generated test methods?

For instance:

`getId()` -> `shouldGetId()`

`doStuff()`-> `shouldDoStuff()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates` and choose `JUnit4 Test Method`. This by default has the form of

```
@org.junit.Test
public void test${NAME}() {
  ${BODY}
}
```

Change to

```
@org.junit.Test
public void should${NAME}() {
  ${BODY}
}
```

[image: File and Code Templates]

Comment: Great, thank you. I tried with `test_${NAME}` but it renders the method name in upper camel case; i.e `getId()` generates  `test_GetId()`. Is there any way to make it generate `test_getId()` instead?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107709?_ga=2.268913073.1188457951.1648359715-51698214.1644906036

Answer (score 3):

You can change the template of the test method easily as follows:

### Step 1:

Create a test class and press ALTR + Insert button in the keyboard and you will see a popup as shown in the following screenshot. Then press the right arrow key on the keyboard and "Edit Template" menu will be opened. Then click on it.

[image]

### Step 2:

Change the method template as required and press on (**In my cause it will be redirected to TestNG method template, but yours will be JUnit**).

[image]

### Step 3:

When you insert a method by ALTR + Insert (Shown in the first step) click on Test Method menu, then it will generate a method as follows:
[image]